# embeding flash in page tab

Tags: facebook, flash, tabs

Anyone have solution to display flash inside Page Tab URL, that works in the newest Chrome? Chrome blocks embedding for security reasons. Console error:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/pages/[CUT] from frame with URL https://[PAGE_TAB_URL]. The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.

I know, that I can display flash in canvas mode (apps.facebook.com/appname), but I want to embed it inside Page Tab.

Comment: That error message usually comes from the JS SDK (and is normal in Chrome). I don’t see how this has any connection to embedding flash …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I once had the same problem, I've built a facebook iframe app that would allow users to use the webcam to take a pic and the .swf responsible for using the webcam, always fired that error.

If you embed a youtube video, chrome will fire that error, but the videos still plays, in my case the .swf object just frozen and I was unable to take any pic or even change flash settings.

The solution was to add this .swf after a user action, in this case a click, just try not embedding the flash on the page, and just put a button that will add the embed code after the user clicks on it.

Comment: Thanks for response - I solved the problem by switching to normal embedding instead of using swfobject.